# How to apply function to every class attribute value?

Tags: ruby, xml-serialization, metaprogramming

I have this super class

```
# encoding: utf-8

class EntidadeCte

  include ROXML
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  class << self
    # apelida o xml_accessor do ROXML para cte_attr
    alias :cte_attr :xml_accessor

    # define um accessor ruby comum para os atributos do cte
    def xml_accessor(*attrs)
      attr_accessor *attrs
    end

    # todos os atributos da entidade
    def cte_attrs
      roxml_attrs.map(&:attr_name)
    end

  end

  # todos os atributos da entidade do objeto
  def cte_attrs
    self.class.cte_attrs
  end

  # retorna o xml representando a entidade
  def to_cte
    doc = Nokogiri::XML::Document.new
    doc.root = to_xml
    doc.serialize
  end

  # retorna o xml ou delega a classe herdada
  def to_s
    self.respond_to? :to_cte ? to_cte : super
  end

end
```

and this subclass

```
# encoding: utf-8

    class TagCte < EntidadeCte

      def initialize
        self.xmlns = "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte"  
      end

      xml_name :CTe

      cte_attr :xmlns, :from => "@xmlns"
      cte_attr :infCte, :as => ConhecimentoTransporte

    end
```

What I'd like to do is, once I call `to_cte` on my subclass object, for it to return its attributes' values but only after applying a function to each one of them. I'd like to normalize their values (remove accents from strings, escape quotes, special characters, etc)  first. How would I do that in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's obviously a lot missing from the code you show here. I surmise that you have certain "attributes" on your entity objects, which are just defined by chaining to `attr_accessor`. In a specific subclass (or subclasses) of `EntitadeCte`, you want some special behavior to be applied to these "attributes".

Are all the "attributes" of the subclass defined directly within that subclass? Or are some of them inherited?

If they are defined directly in the subclass, you can simply redefine `cte_attr` in the subclass, something like:

```
class Subclass < EntitadeCte
  def self.cte_attr(*attrs)
    attrs.each do |attr|
      attr_writer(attr)
      class_eval("def #{attr}; do something special to @#{attr} here; end")
    end
  end
end
```

So rather than using `attr_accessor`, you define your own equivalent "class macro", which adds some special behavior to the reader.

**UPDATE:** from your comment, it sounds like *all* the subclasses of `EntitadeCte` require the same special handling of attributes. Is that right? In that case, you can just change the definition of `cte_attr` in the superclass, to something like the sample code above.

OR, you could define `cte_attr` (in the superclass) to generate *2* reader methods, one which normalizes the attribute values, and one which doesn't. Then write a `to_cte` method which uses the "normalized" attribute readers.

There are all kinds of options. If the choices which I've given you here do not meet your needs, then you need to be more specific about what you want to do. Is the problem that some subclasses are supposed to use "normalized" attributes, while others are supposed to use "non-normalized" attributes? Or is the problem that you want to turn "normalization" on and off dynamically?

Comment: I have several subclasses of `EntidadeCte`, and all their attrs are marked with `cte_attr:` (subclass attrs). These subclasses represent a very complex XML structure used by our government here in Brazil and yes, they're associated with each other so all I have to do is call `to_cte` on my root object in order to get the whole XML. What I'm doing is setting these attrs values in order to generate the XML that has to be sent over via SOAP.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to change the code in every single subclass.

Comment: Just added more options for you.

Comment: Ended up creating another attr_reader in my super class and using it inside `to_cte` like you said (2nd option). Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!